# IntelliJ - How to use a different ssh key

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, rsa

I have 2 github accounts
A company one and a personal one

I use cygwin to manage my ssh keys and connect to Github

Everything works fine In IntelliJ when using the corporate account since it uses the the default .ssh/id_rsa key

Everthing works fine in Cygwin using my Personal Account since I can use the the "ssh-add ~/.ssh/ide_rsa_otherkeyfile" command and then use all git commands via command line

But IntelliJ always default to the "id_rsa" file so I can not connect to my personal repo.

Is there a way for IntelliJ to use the other rsa key?

All this RSA and cygwin is way above my linux command line experience level.

Note:
I also created the config file in .ssh directory to facilitate multiple github accounts

```
Default GitHub user (corporate account) 
Host github.com HostName
github.com User git IdentityFile/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa

Client user (personal account)
Host github-client
HostName github.com
User git IdentityFile /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa_perso
```

*In short what this does is tells SSH to use the client key when connecting to the server github-client, which is really github.com.*

If no one has a solution I am aware that it would be easier to invite my corporate account as a contributor but then I woul have commits under 2 seperate email account.

Comment: If IntelliJ does respect the config file, using an address like `github-client:aGitRepoName` should be enough for IntelliJ to use the other ssh key.

Answer (score 14):

When checking out your project from Version Control System, use `<host-from-ssh-config>:<github-username>/<repository>` format as [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) mentioned.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com-activehacker
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /Users/andrey/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From [Using Git integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html):

> IntelliJ IDEA supports the standard method of using multiple ssh keys,
>   by means of creating .ssh/config file.